# In Go How to delete an item from slice of an Struct

Tags: go, slice

I have struct containing a slice of another struct. I have added methods for Addition and Deletion of an item from the slice but addition is working deletion is not. I am new to Go so I am not able to understand why slice reassignment does not gets reflected in struct

Short Version of my code below. Link to PlayGoLang : http://play.golang.org/p/4NnGh3Dtzw

```
 type BatteryTest struct {
    Name, LocalConf, JdkPath, SysProps, LocalconfPath string
    NumberOfNodes                                     int
    }

    type Server struct {
    Port                                    int
    TestQueue, CompletedTests, RunningTests []BatteryTest
}

    func (this *Server) AddBatteryTest(test BatteryTest) error {    
        this.TestQueue = append(this.TestQueue, test)
        return nil
    }

func (this *Server) TakeBatteryTest() error {
    length := len(this.TestQueue)
    if length == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Len==", 0)
        return errors.New("Queue is empty")
    }

    slice := this.TestQueue
    i := len(this.TestQueue) - 1
    slice = append(slice[:i], slice[i+1:]...)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Using `this` as a receiver name is undesirable and [not recommended](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names).

Comment: Thanks Dave. Java Hangover. I followed a tutorial which had "this" used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning `slice` back to `this.TestQueue`

Comment: I changed the code again with re-assgining slice back to this.TestQueue still not working : http://play.golang.org/p/gYvp1a5OA0

Comment: You playground code is using the old `remainingTests` var, you need to call `server.GetRemainingTests()` again.  You should also name your error values `err` instead of `error`, since `error` is a builtin type. [here](http://play.golang.org/p/TYKRi9IBVh) is an updated working version.